# Close fullscreen flash from JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lightview window that needs to appear when an item in a fullscreen flash movie is clicked. SO i want to put into the lightview callback a bit of JS that will close the fullscreen flash movie. Is it possible to close a fullscreen flash movie in JS?

Comment: You have no access to the swf source?

Comment: With "close" you mean to just exit the fullscreen mode but still keep playing the movie?

Comment: you can invoke swf object's method if object exposes and you know them. have look at this example http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/.

Comment: As in exit fullscreen altogether. The flash in question is cooliris. I cannot see a method in cooliris that allows you to close the fullscreen option from javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need make in SWF method, which checks fullscreen status.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var FULLSCREEN = 1;

function check_fullscreen() {
  return FULLSCREEN;
}

function turn_off_fullscreen() {
    FULLSCREEN = 0;
}
```

**FLASH:**

```
if (!ExternalInterface.call("check_fullscreen"))
    //turn off fullscreen
```

If you wanna don't allow fullscreen all time, when use embed flash param (in html):

```
<param name="allowFullscreen" value="false">
```